# Difference and usage of uri (e.g. get_directory_uri) and absolute path (e.g. get_directory)

Tags: permalinks, urls, links, directory

What is the difference uri (e.g. get_directory_uri) and absolute path (e.g. get_directory) and when it the best time to use each?

Comment: The context of each function is differente: `get_template_directory()` returns absolute path within the file system of the server; you can not use this path to access a resource from Internet.  `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the URI, which identify a resource in Internet and can be used to access the resource from the web. Appart of that, @Howdy_McGee answer explain most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to:

- [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)
- [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

`get_template_directory()` is an absolute path - so if you're including a PHP file that is in your template directory this would be a good function to use. If you're using a child theme and need to reference something in the parent theme you could also use this function.

`get_template_directory_uri()` is the URL to the theme directory: http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/ - if you're using a child theme and need to *link* to something in the parent theme you could use this. If you're using a single theme and want to enqueue a Javascript file you could use this function to easily get your theme folder:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```